# How to remove widget's title in Liferay's custom theme

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-7, liferay-theme

I created a custom theme for Liferay 7.2 through IDE. When I try to modify "Look and feel" setting of any widget, I'm unable to remove the title or to see the option's dropdown of "Application Decorators".

I followed this [tutorial](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-2/frameworks/-/knowledge_base/f/making-configurable-theme-settings) and created the "liferay-look-and-feel.xml". With this file the option's dropdown is now visible, but I still cannot remove any title. Even selecting "Barebone" option and "No" in "Use Custom Title".

I printed the portlet preferences, and the "portletSetupUseCustomTitle" property is set to false

Probably, I have a missing configuration on my Theme's settings but I'm not aware about which one is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In your custom theme find  portlet.ftl file Add this line where title are shown
   <#if portlet_display.getPortletDecoratorId() != "barebone">
            <div class="autofit-col autofit-col-expand">
            <h2 class="portlet-title-text">${portlet_title}</h2>
            </div>
  </#if>
```